# Signo * (asterísco en una variable) ¿para qué es?

Tags: c++, variables

Soy muy nuevo en esto de programar, mientras estudiaba noté lo siguiente:

```
int * apuntador = &variable;
```

Entonces me saltó la duda sobre qué función tiene ese asterísco en medio de la variable.

Comment: Es el operador puntero. Puede contener una dirección de memoria del tipo indicado. Funciona junto con el operador &, que te da la dirección de memoria dónde está la variable. Echa un vistazo por Google sobre `punteros en C`

Comment: Te dejo aquí un enlace que explica muy bien los punteros, concepto que me ha costado bastante entender. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OgX4vdtkkHQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estas leyendo la definición de una variable:

```
   int * apuntador = &variable;
// ~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~
// tipo    nombre    valor inicial
```

El tipo de la variable es `int *`, puedes pensar en el asterisco como si fuera una especie de "*apellido*" del tipo, este apellido hace que pertenezca a la familia de los punteros. Cualquier tipo acompañado de un asterisco será un puntero al tipo:

```
int * pi;        // Puntero a int
float * pf;      // Puntero a float
int ** ppi;      // Puntero a puntero a int
Cocodrilo * pcc; // Puntero a Cocodrilo
```

Los punteros sirven para apuntar<sup>1</sup> a los datos de los que son punteros:

```
Zariguella z;
pcc = &z; // Error, un puntero a Cocodrilo no puede apuntar a Zariguella.

double d;
pi = &d; // Error, un punetro a int no puede apuntar a double.

ppi = &pi; // Correcto, un puntero a puntero a int puede apuntar a puntero a int.
```

Sólo para completar, el [operador et `&`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%26) devuelve la dirección de memoria de un objeto, es eso lo que necesita un puntero para apuntar.

---

1. [Gracias, capitán obviedad](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50400906#50400906).

Comment: Mejor no lo pudiste explicar. ¡Muchas gracias! 